# « Entr'aimer » et « entraider »

Tags: orthographe, histoire, élision, évolution

Deux verbes pronominaux (réciproques) apparemment similaires.

> (s') entr'aimer vs (s') entraider

L'un sans apostrophe et l'autre avec apostrophe. Pourquoi entraider sans apostrophe et entr'aimer avec ? Quelle logique dicte l'apostrophe ici ?

Comment: Parce que "entraimer" n'existe pas.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Merci. La question demeure cependant. Peut-être différemment posée. Pourquoi entraider sans apostrophe et entr'aimer avec ? Quelle logique dicte l'apostrophe ici ?

Comment: Je pense que c'est juste ça : entraider n'a pas d'apostrophe car c'est un verbe à part entière, alors que "entr'aimer" est juste obtenu en collant "entre" et "aimer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selon le Wikitionnaire :

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/entr%E2%80%99aider

entr’aider existait il y a un temps. C'est une ancienne orthographe d'entraider.

1. (Désuet) Ancienne orthographe de entraider.

   Il se faut entr’aider, c’est la loi de nature. — (Jean de La Fontaine, L’Âne et le Chien, Fables VIII, 17)

Désuet : qui n’est plus employé par la langue moderne → voir vieilli et archaïque.

Mon avis est qu'« entraider » et antérieurement « entr'aider » sont beaucoup plus utilisés qu' « entr'aimer ».

On entend un peu partout, dans la vie quotidienne, dans la littérature ou dans les journaux le verbe entraider, tandis qu'entraimer est moins courant, au contraire d'aimer tout simplement. Le fait que l'apostrophe soit peut courante en plein milieu de mots et qu'entraider est plus simple d'utilisation qu'entr'aider, a sûrement conduit à ce changement. Je pense qu'il n'est pas impossible non plus que dans le futur, entraimer existe à la place d'entr'aimer, bien que comme dit pécédemment, le fait que ce verbe soit nettement moins utilisé contribue à ce que ça ne soit pas encore fait.

Pour appuyer mes propos qui concernent la fréquence d'utilisation, entraider ou entr'aider ont été tapés environ 1 000 fois sur Google durant les 12 derniers mois, tandis que le verbe entr'aimer ou entraimer ont été cherché moins de 10 fois sur Google seulement durant cette même période. Source : https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=FR&q=entraider,entr%27aimer

Comment: Ouiii, je suis sûr que la fréquence et l'âge des expressions jouent un rôle. Plus un mot composé se dit, plus il devient un seul mot aux yeux des locuteurs, et une orthographe sans apostrophes suit.

Comment: @LukeSawczak *Aujourd'hui* est une exception. Il s'agit d'un seul mot depuis longtemps mais son apostrophe a résisté.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est vrai. On dirait que les mots les plus fréquents résistent très bien aux forces normalisantes, de façon très paradoxe !

Answer (score 4):

La réponse, s'il faut en croire Grevisse (*Le Bon Usage*, 14e édition, §45 R1) est beaucoup plus bête: dans l'édition de 1932 du Dictionnaire de l'académie française, les apostrophes dans les verbes commençant par *entr*+voyelle (incluant *entr'aider* qui s'écrivaient encore communément ainsi dans la deuxième moitié du 19e siècle) furent supprimées... mais celles des verbes *entr'aimer*, *entr'apercevoir*, *entr'égorger*, *entr'appeler* et *entr'avertir* ne le furent pas sans qu'on sache trop pourquoi, laissant persister une orthographe ancienne sans raison!

Si ce n'était de cet accident historique, ces orthographes ne persisteraient pas dans la 9e édition (2001), qui admet les deux possibilités uniquement pour ces verbes.

C'est un peu comme le *i* de *oignon*, longtemps seul survivant de l'époque où il empêchait qu'on prononce -gn- avec deux consonnes comme dans *gnome*, d'ailleurs, c'est le même *i* dans *Montaigne*, que cet auteur faisait bel et bien rimer avec *montagne*!

(NB: pour ceux qui aiment utiliser le [site du CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/), ces verbes ne s'y trouvent pas dans la lexicographie de l'Académie, et je ne saurais dire pourquoi, mais ils sont bel et bien dans la base de données de l'[ARTFL](https://artflsrv03.uchicago.edu/philologic4/publicdicos/) pour la 8e édition)

Comment: On les trouve plus difficilement ds. Ac.8 sur CNRTL en faisant précéder du pronom réfl. « se » : « [se entr'aimer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/se%20entr'aimer) » sauf pour « entr'apercevoir ». Merci !

Answer (score -1):

`Entraider` correspond à l'action de l'entraide. `Entraide` est un nom existant et c'est ce à quoi fait référence le verbe `entraider`.

`Entr'aimer` ne correspond pas à l'action de l'entraime car ce nom n'existe pas (et n'aurait pas de sens). Il fait donc directement référence à `entre` et à `aimer` d'où cette orthographe.

Comment: La logique ne tient pas, *entraide* étant postérieur et décrit comme un déverbal d'entr(')aider et non le contraire. D'autre part, s'il faut dériver un substantif d'*entr'aimer*, c'est *entr'amour*.